# Remove XML Record based on date node

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML file that has loads of records that I don't need, the XML file is being few into  WordPress via XMLRPC. What I need to do is strip all records based on the date that I don't need so that I don't have hundreds of duplicated posts via PHP. MY XML file is formatted as so:

```
<data>
 <in>
   <a>First Name</a>
   <b>Surname </b>
   <c>07:00:00 11/08/2012</c>
 </in>
 <in>
   <a>First Name</a>
   <b>Surname </b>
   <c>08:00:00 11/09/2012</c>
 </in>
 <in>
   <a>First Name</a>
   <b>Surname </b>
   <c>09:00:00 11/10/2012</c>
 </in>
</data>
```

So I need to check whether  is yesterday, if it is keep the  record, if it's before that to delete it from the XML file. From hunting around I have this so far:

```
<?php

$DATE = date( "Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-1, date("y")) );
$searchString = '';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$doc->load('file' . $DATE . '.xml');

$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = sprintf('//in[./c[contains(., "%s")]]', $searchString);
foreach($xPath->query() as $node) {
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

If this will work then I guess I just need the correct searchstring, sorry I'm not great with xPath

Comment: You need to put the `$query` variable into the `query()` call. Also `. = "%s"` should already work. Apart from that I'd say it looks good already. --- http://eval.in/2668

Comment: This can be done very easily and entirely with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, that's the issue I think how do I make the variable to delete everything apart from yesterday? I know the first date in the file so I guess I need to create a new variable for the first date and then compare this to yesterday and if it's between the two then to delete the records? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the `<c>` tag will always contain the date, and the document will always be structured like your example, then XPath is unnecessarily complicating your solution.  Instead, just use `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
$lastDt = new DateTime(/* date of the last item you recorded goes here */);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load(/* path to your XML file goes here */);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('c') as $node) {
    $dt = new DateTime($node->nodeValue);

    if ($dt <= $lastDt) {
        $in = $node->parentNode;
        $in->parentNode->removeChild($in);
    }
}
```